# Mongodb error on starting

Tags: mongodb, terminal

When i start mongo db it instantly crashes and goes back to the normal command line. I am on Mac runing the MEAN stack if that helps. Below is the error:

$sudo mongod

```
Sun Jun  1 21:01:01.728 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=47937 port=3000 dbpath=/usr/local/var/mongodb 64-bit host=NoHax4You
Sun Jun  1 21:01:01.728 [initandlisten] 
Sun Jun  1 21:01:01.729 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Sun Jun  1 21:01:01.729 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.9
Sun Jun  1 21:01:01.729 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Sun Jun  1 21:01:01.729 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin minimavericks.local 13.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Sun Jun  1 21:01:01.729 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Sun Jun  1 21:01:01.729 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", dbpath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log", port: 3000 }
Sun Jun  1 21:01:01.729 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10310 Unable to lock file: /usr/local/var/mongodb/mongod.lock. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
Sun Jun  1 21:01:01.729 dbexit: 
Sun Jun  1 21:01:01.729 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sun Jun  1 21:01:01.729 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sun Jun  1 21:01:01.729 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sun Jun  1 21:01:01.729 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sun Jun  1 21:01:01.729 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Sun Jun  1 21:01:01.729 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Sun Jun  1 21:01:01.729 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Sun Jun  1 21:01:01.729 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Sun Jun  1 21:01:01.729 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Thanks,
Ewan

Comment: try running it on a different port...

Comment: tried running mongod --port 3000 and still the same issue. I have updated error report above

Comment: Do you have any data stored in your MongoDB yet? If no, there is a quick fix: delete /data and then create the /data/db directory again.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

First of all, look for other instances of mongod running on the system using the age-old command:

```
ps ax | grep mongod
```

If you see a line like -

```
98555   ??  S      4:40.89 mongod --dbpath /Volumes/ComputerName/data/db 
-PID-                      -name-          -------------path------------
```

then there is a mongod process running already. If so kill it and then start mongod again.

To kill a process with PID = 0000, in Unix like environment use -

```
kill -9 0000
```

If your console returns something like, `-bash: kill: (98555) - Operation not permitted`, use

```
sudo !!
```

to [repeat the command as super user](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo). This should get you going.

---

PS: *If you haven't stored any data in your db yet, delete `/data` and then create the `/data/db` directory again. Do a `sudo mongod` and it should work.*

Comment: How is this age old command not talked about! thanks so much. To give future people a hand i ran through my process below using these instructions.

Comment: Having identified the process, you can sometimes kill it using "sudo kill -9 <process number>".

Comment: Its written everywhere that it is a bad idea to kill -9 the mongodb process. It can brake your  db or something.

Comment: Recreating the data/db folder didn't do anything for me. Sudo'ing the mongod command worked.

Comment: @BenRacicot: I suggested deleting `/data` because there is no sense in keeping empty folder hierarchy. It has to be succeeded by a `sudo mongod` so that MongoDB can create its fresh folder hierarchy. So, if you haven't added any data, but you have folders - they are safe to delete.

Comment: On OSX in the terminal => killall -9 mongod worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and this one liner fix my issue

```
killall mongod
```

Run the above command inside your **Terminal**

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -2):

I first opened the /data/db/mongod.lock file, found my process number there, then killed it with `kill -9 <processnumber>`. That worked for me.