# Issue running MongoDB on mac 'Unable to lock the lock file'

Tags: mongodb, macos

I'm having trouble running MongoDB on my mac. MongoDB is the first database I've ever played with (I'm doing a tutorial) so I'm a bit lost.

I'm getting the following error in my terminal:

```
Joshuas-MacBook-Pro:~ joshua$ mongod
2018-07-25T14:11:36.709+0100 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2018-07-25T14:11:36.725+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=10623 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Joshuas-MacBook-Pro.local
2018-07-25T14:11:36.725+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.0
2018-07-25T14:11:36.725+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3b07af3d4f471ae89e8186d33bbb1d5259597d51
2018-07-25T14:11:36.725+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2018-07-25T14:11:36.725+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-07-25T14:11:36.725+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-07-25T14:11:36.725+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-07-25T14:11:36.725+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-07-25T14:11:36.725+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2018-07-25T14:11:36.725+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: DBPathInUse: Unable to lock the lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock (Resource temporarily unavailable). Another mongod instance is already running on the /data/db directory, terminating
2018-07-25T14:11:36.725+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-07-25T14:11:36.725+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
Joshuas-MacBook-Pro:~ joshua$
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I can do to fix it? I haven't seen any posts with people getting the 'Unable to lock the lock file' issue.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already `mongod` instance is running and using `dbPath`.

1. You don't need to start again.
2. Stop or kill all mongo instance first and then start again.

   - Upstart: `sudo service mongodb stop`
   - Sysvinit: `sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb stop`

**Or on Mac OS X:**

- Find PID of mongod process using `$ top`
- Kill the process by `$ kill <PID>` ([Mongo docs for more information](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#use-kill))

Comment: Thank you, however I don't think that I can find my mongodb instance running: 
fud, quicklookd,  top, Google Chrom, corecaptured,  ocspd, MTLCompilerS - is the list of things that appear when I do top, however I am still getting the same error

Comment: also, when you say kill <PID> would I type in the name or the PID number?

Comment: Your log says some other mongo instance is running and using the same path for storage. PID number only

Comment: Do you have any tips of what I should do from here if I cannot find the instance with top? If I restart my computer will that stop the MongoDB from running?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23983976/9369945 check this. Restarting the computer may help you. but I would prefer to find the running instance first.

Comment: Thank you, that worked, for some reason the instance wasn't showing up on top, but was showing up there.